# "Падло с быдлом на плавидле"

Tags: этимология

Думаю, многие знают это забавное чешское выражение, которое на самом деле означает "статного парня с веслом, находящегося на лодке". Но вот интересно, что в русском-то языке первые два слова - достаточно нехорошие ругательства. Интересно было бы узнать, как вышло, что в одном языке это вполне нормальные слова, а в другом - оскорбление и брань? Какое изначальное значение этих слов?

[image]

Comment: Сайт [Путеводитель по Чехии и Словакии](http://www.nazdar.ru/index.php?id=9) пишет: "Б**и**дло с падл**е**м на плавидле" означает "Багор с веслом на плавсредстве". Слово "падло" происходит от английского слова "to paddle" - "грести", но чехи скорее употребляют слово "весло".

Comment: Интересно, кто писал  этот путеводитель?  багор, по гуглу  - tančírna,  весло - pádlo, это да. bidlo - окунь.  Там диакритические знаки над гласными очень важны...

Comment: Есть еще версия где "бидло" - шест. Поскольку в чешском не эксперт пишу как комментарии.

Comment: Ну, багор от шеста в принципе не далеко ушел...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прежде всего поправлю вашу фразу. Как она пишется по-чешски, не знаю, но "по-русски" надо бы: *быдло с падлем на плавидле*.
С плавидлом все ясно. Плавает - вот и плавидло, это скорее судно по-чешски.
Падло - весло. Потому, наверное, что все время *падает* в воду при гребле.
Быдло - как утверждается, статный парень, мОлодец (?) Точно сказать трудно. Фасмер указывает в статье "Быдло", что *bydlo* (чеш.) - жилище, местопреБЫвание. Общеславянский корень "быть" здесь очевиден. Позже *быдло* в некоторых славянских языках стало обозначать скот, отсюда и ругательное значение слова. Имеет ли оно в чешском вышеназванный побочный смысл ("статный парень"), и почему необходима справка специалиста по языку. Нынешние сетевые переводчики бессильны в этом вопросе.
Возможен и элементарный розыгрыш с этой фразой.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you spread such a nonsence?
*Pádlo* is a type of veslo. We recognize between pádlo and veslo. There is veslo/vesla in your picture: long, mostly two, connected with boat/ship. *Pádlo* means just one, short, held by hands like onto canoe.
Bidlo is a long rod, e.g. gondoliers in Venice use it. And it does NOT mean "pareň" at all. Where did you hear it? It is only possible to use it as an ordinary comparison, e.g. if I say *she is such a "bidlo"* - it means she is very tall and very slim (not very significant feminine signs). But it is just comparison, not used commonly, I've never heard it in reality.
Plavidlo is generally whatever sailing, not used commonly in speech. I think that words *plavidlo* and *vozidlo* were created for traffic rules.
Your sentence is fake, Czech language has about 300000 words and twenty of them have this suffix. I even noticed that Russians create fake, non existing words in the net.

Comment: thanks for your answer. BTW, does the word "bydlo" (not "bidlo") exists in Czech?

Answer (score 0):

Может быть "быдло" у чехов соответствует нашему "бугай" (?)

Comment: Я не нашел с чешском словаре подходящего слова.

Comment: Я не нашел в чешском словаре подходящего слова. Bydlom - глагол, z bidlem - вдвоем. Надстрочные знаки (а может быть в них все дело) вопрсоизвести тут не могу.